# Cannot access files in colab

Tags: bash, google-colaboratory, hdf5

I am trying to put a folder into my colab for a project.I have the commands below into a cell which I am trying to run:

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')
```

then below that I will

```
!pwd
```

to get an understanding of where I am,which gives me:

```
/content
```

then I will use the command

```
!ls
```

which tells me that I have two directories:

```
drive  sample_data
```

The problem begins when I try to

```
!cd /drive/
```

in which I am being told

```
/bin/bash: line 0: cd: /drive/: No such file or directory
```

The problem is I want to go somewhere where I have dumped my files and these bash commands don't seem to be helping much.So basically the !cd doesn't help in moving to the right directories.

Comment: try:  `!cd drive/`

Comment: or `cd /content/drive`

Comment: None seem to work!